# Exclude direct paths on server, i.e. css, js, etc

Tags: php, url, routes, laravel, laravel-4

I am experimenting with Laravel 4, I have successfully installed and did a couple things and that. Unfortunately, I cannot load any CSS into my HTML.

The CSS url is correct, which I used `HTML::style('css/bootstrap.css');` to generate for me.

When I access the URL (currently on localhost) `http://laravel.dev/css/bootstrap.css`, it gives me an error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested resource /css/bootstrap.css was not found on this server.

The file is stored in `/public/css/bootstrap.css`, why can't Laravel avoid this? How would I overcome this issue? It seems that the route is going forward with the application rather than finding the file on the server.

I am running Laravel on my localhost environment, PHP 5.4.0, Mac OS X 10.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a problem with your virtual host or .haccess file, because

```
HTML::style('css/bootstrap.css');
```

Should point to

```
http://laravel.dev/css/bootstrap.css
```

And it is doing it correctly, but your virtual host configuration for http://laravel.dev/ should point to

```
/var/www/laravel.dev/public/
```

So, that file, in fact, is

```
/var/www/laravel.dev/public/css/bootstrap.css
```

If you get a file not found on

```
/css/bootstrap.css
```

Then I have to assume this is a virtual host or rewrite (.htaccess) configuration problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the assets folders in your root outside public directory according to `HTML::style`.

Otherwise you can access by `http://laravel.dev/public/css/bootstrap.css`